# iPhone keyboard tweak

Tags: iphone, keyboard

I would reduce the time to get special characters when keeping a touch on the keyboard. Anyone has a clue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly doubt this is possible using the public API. You'd have a file bug with Apple to ask them to make this possible. It does however seem unlikely, as it would result in differing behavior between apps in a common control.

Answer (score 2):

(Undocumented) Override `-[UIKeyboardImpl touchLongPressTimer]` to call

```
-(void)touchLongPressTimer {
   [self touchLongPressTimerWithDelay:0.5f]; // default = 1.8125f
}
```

Comment: Using undocumented calls = significantly increased risk of rejection

Comment: Not significantly increased, that's 100% possibility of rejection. (Maybe OP doesn't target AppStore, who knows?)

Comment: Well sorry, I didn't make myself clear.
I'm not developing an app, I was asking how to change that time in Apple apps (Messages, Mail, etc…).
Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own keyboard control for your own app :)